# How can I hide a button when scrolled to the top of a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to adapt this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8sHN/8/) to make the menu button on my website hide when I'm at the top of the page and show when I start scrolling down.

I modified the JS to match the CSS on [my site](http://concepttest.concept9.ca/). Then I placed it in  tags in the head of my page

```
var $scb = $('<div class="toggle-menu-wrap"></div>');
$('.top-header').append($scb);
var $ccol = $('.content');

$ccol.scroll(function(){
    $scb.stop(true,true).fadeTo(500, $ccol.scrollTop() > 10 ? 1 : 0);
});
```

However, it still doesn't work. Am I making a mistake in how I'm modifying the JS to fit my CSS?

Comment: You need to put that code inside document ready function

Comment: add event to window instead of content 
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $scb.stop(true,true).fadeTo(500, $ccol.scrollTop() > 10 ? 1 : 0);
});

Comment: Thanks for all the help Alex (and others!)! In the end what worked well was Alex's suggestions : adding the .toggle-menu-wrap {display:none;} and "jQuery(document).ready(function() { fadeMenuWrap(); jQuery(window).scroll(function() { fadeMenuWrap(); }); function fadeMenuWrap() { var top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; if (top > 300) { jQuery('.toggle-menu-wrap').fadeIn(300); } else { jQuery('.toggle-menu-wrap').fadeOut(300); } } }); "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can include the toggle-menu-wrap element in your HTML from the start. There is no need to insert it using JS.
2. Write the one line of CSS you need, which is to hide the element from the beginning

   .toggle-menu-wrap { 
       display: none; 
   }
3. Your version of jQuery uses 'jQuery' instead of '$' to reference itself. I would also re-write your JS like:

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
       fadeMenuWrap(); 
       jQuery(window).scroll(fadeMenuWrap);
   });

   function fadeMenuWrap() { 
       var scrollPos = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
       if (scrollPos > 300) { 
           jQuery('.toggle-menu-wrap').fadeIn(300); 
       } else { 
           jQuery('.toggle-menu-wrap').fadeOut(300); 
       } 
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks Alex - I replaced the code with the document.ready. I guess I also had to add to custom.css the following : .toggle-menu-wrap {display:none;}. I'm sure i'm still missing something...

Comment: So it is still not working for you? Update the page that sits on the server and I can take another look.

Comment: Still not working :( I updated it - line 278 -  http://concepttest.concept9.ca/ - maybe it's related to the CSS elements?:s

Comment: No, you are still getting a console error. It's JS related. Looking into

Comment: Ok, the version of jQuery you are including does not use '$' to reference itself but the word 'jQuery'. Therefore, replace all '$' in your script tag with the word 'jQuery' exactly like that. Ex: "jQuery(document).ready(function() {"

Comment: really appreciate it Alex - slowly getting the hang of this. Replaced all the relevant tags with jQuery and eliminated the error, but it's still not functioning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64612/discussion-between-alex-and-dan).

Comment: Thanks for all the help Alex! In the end what worked was this:

adding the .toggle-menu-wrap {display:none;}

+ 

jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

fadeMenuWrap(); 

jQuery(window).scroll(function() { 
fadeMenuWrap(); 
}); 

function fadeMenuWrap() { 
var top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
if (top > 300) { 
jQuery('.toggle-menu-wrap').fadeIn(300); 
} else { 
jQuery('.toggle-menu-wrap').fadeOut(300); 
} 
} 
});

Comment: @Alex You only need to use `jQuery(window).scroll(fadeMenuWrap)`. Wrapping the wrapper in an anonymous function is sort of silly.

Comment: @royhowie like that (edited above), where I separate the doc ready and scroll blocks?

Comment: I submitted an edit, but `jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    fadeMenuWrap(); 
    jQuery(window).scroll(fadeMenuWrap);
});`. Keep the rest the same.

Answer (score 1):

Like @murli2308 said in the comments above, you need to attach a scroll event listener to the window:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $scb = $('<div class="scroll-border"></div>');
    $('.above').append($scb);
    var $ccol = $('.content');

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $scb.stop(true,true).fadeTo(500, $ccol.scrollTop() > 10 ? 1 : 0);
    });
})
```

Wrapping your code in  `$(document).ready()` would also be a good idea.

The reason `$ccol.scroll(function() { ...` works in that fiddle is because of the CSS:

```
.content{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Notice `overflow: auto;`. This causes that specific div to be scrollable. However, on your website, you scroll the entire page, not `$ccol`. This means the event handler will never fire a scroll event (since `$ccol` will never scroll).

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten to link Jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

Link this inside your head tag incase.....

Comment: Yes, he has jQuery included on the page, above where this script runs.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $(".your_element").css("display", "block");
    } else {
        $(".your_element").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```